# parse.com / iOS - Is there a way to download the whole class object in json format?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parse-platform

I am testing parse.com and I am creating an app that needs to work offline.

I would like to download the whole class object in json format in order to save it locally and access the data.

I cannot find any documentation on how to do it using Swift/iOS.

I successfully get the object with a specific ID using:

```
       var query = PFQuery(className:"TestObject")
       query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("DuZIpSgjnt") {
            (TestObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && TestObject != nil {
                println(TestObject)
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        }
```

but not the whole class.

What I would like to retrieve is the same json response that I get using REST Api from curl:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

that returns all my objects in json:

> {"results":[{"cheatMode":false,"createdAt":"2015-05-15T15:55:17.782Z","objectId":"IKCmjRVet9","playerName":"Sean Plott","score":1337,"updatedAt":"2015-05-15T15:55:17.782Z"},{"cheatMode":false,"createdAt":"2015-05-15T16:05:51.688Z","objectId":"UOKOZkxaGl","playerName":"Marco xxx","score":9998,"updatedAt":"2015-05-15T16:05:51.688Z"}]}

any help appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by getting the whole class? Getting all objects from a class?

Comment: @Flying_Banana yes, all the objects

Comment: @Flying_Banana i edited my question to make it more clear. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data persistently, I suggest that you first enable the local datastore, as described below:

[Local datastore for Parse iOS](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore)

So the operation is basically a fetch then a pin. A fetch looks like:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourCustomClassName"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *err) {
    if (!err) {
        // Do something with your objects, e.g. pin them for later access.
    }
}];
```

Pinning just means parse is now storing the pinned data for you locally. you can fetch them later locally by marking you query as such:

```
[query fromLocalDatastore];
```

Comment: Thank you. perfect. Do you know how to print the results in JSON?

Comment: I think the data is sent in JSON format. Did you try just a plain print statement for each object?

Comment: yes i am printing the object "objects" but it doesn't look Json